# Reading columns of data for every point in a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to read the second column of data with the title `nodes` and assign to a variable with the same name for each point of `t1`.

```
import csv

with open('Data_10x10.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
```

The data looks like

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv_reader = csv.reader(f)` is a **Generator**. So you can skip the headers by execute `heading = next(csv_reader)`.

I would just use a dictionary `data_t1` for storing node data with key name of column `t1`.

Try below one.

```py
import csv

with open('Data_10x10.csv', 'r') as f:
    data_t1={}
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skips the heading
    heading = next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        data_t1[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Accessing data (key should be value of you t1 column, in this case '0', '1' etc.)
`print(data_t1['0'])`
`print(data_t1['1'])`

If you want to create dynamic variables with the same name for each point of `t1` It is really bad idea. If your csv has lot of rows maybe millions, it will create millions of variables. So use `dictionary` with key and values.